# Segue historyArray values into UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a calculator that i have created in swift. I am trying to add another functionality to it, I would like to pass my history of the operations that have been pressed that are stored in my historyArray into my TableViewController. I am attempting to segue the data, but can't seem to get it. I have a couple different prepare for segue methods that I was playing around with that are commented out. Here is my code so far:

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var HistoryLabel: UILabel!

    var historyArray: [String] = []
    var userIsTypingNumbers = false
    var firstNumber = 0
    var secondNumber = 0
    var operation = ""
    var result = 0.0

    @IBAction private func NumbersEntered(_ sender: UIButton) {

        //know what number is being pressed
        let number = sender.currentTitle
        //if user is typing number, do this.
        if userIsTypingNumbers {
            //specify what number is being pressed.
            //append the number onto the previous number.
            displayLabel.text = displayLabel.text! + number!
        } else {
            displayLabel.text = number
            userIsTypingNumbers = true
        }
    }
    var displayValue: Double {

        get {
            return Double(displayLabel.text!)!
        }
        set {
            displayLabel.text = String(newValue)
        }
    }

    private var calculations = PerformCalculations()


    @IBAction func OperationsPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        userIsTypingNumbers = false
        firstNumber = Int(Double(displayLabel.text!)!)
        operation = sender.currentTitle!
        if operation == "√" {
            result = (PerformCalculations().squareroot(a: Double(firstNumber)))
            displayLabel.text = String(result)
        }
    }


    @IBAction func Enter(_ sender: UIButton) {
        userIsTypingNumbers = false
        secondNumber = Int(Double(displayLabel.text!)!)


        if operation == "+" {
            result = (PerformCalculations().add(a: Double(firstNumber), b: Double(secondNumber)))
        } else if operation == "÷" {
            result = (PerformCalculations().division(a: Double(firstNumber), b: Double(secondNumber)))
        } else if operation == "×" {
            result = (PerformCalculations().multiplication(a: Double(firstNumber), b: Double(secondNumber)))
        } else if operation == "-" {
            result = (PerformCalculations().subtract(a: Double(firstNumber), b: Double(secondNumber)))
        }
        displayLabel.text = String(result)

        historyArray.append("\(firstNumber) \(operation) \(secondNumber) = \(result)")
        userIsTypingNumbers = false

        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "History", sender: self)

    }


    @IBAction func Clear(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //clear display to 0.
        displayLabel.text = "0"
    }

    @IBAction func Delete(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //deleting last typed number, if user messed up.
        let name: String = self.displayLabel.text!
        //count number of characters.
        let stringLength = name.characters.count
        let substringIndex = stringLength - 1
        displayLabel.text = (name as NSString).substring(to: substringIndex)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "History" {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? TableTableViewController {
                destinationVC.dataString = historyArray.description
            }
        }
    }*/

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destViewController : TableTableViewController = segue.destination as! TableTableViewController

        destViewController.dataString = historyArray.description

    }
}
```

Model.swift

```
import Foundation


class PerformCalculations {

    func add(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
        let result = a + b
        return result
    }
    func division(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
        let result = a / b
        return result
    }
    func subtract(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
        let result = a - b
        return result
    }
    func multiplication(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
        let result = a * b
        return result
    }
    func squareroot(a: Double) -> Double {
        let result = sqrt(a)
        return result
    }
}
```

TableTableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class TableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //var dataString:String!

    var historyArray: [String] = []
    var i = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        i = 0
        while i < historyArray.count{
            AddLabel(history: historyArray[i])
            i = i+1
        }

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

        func AddLabel(history: String){
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = history
        let y = i*15
        label.frame = CGRect(x:125,y:y,width:200,height:21)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }

    /*
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thank You!

Comment: what issue you are faced ?

Comment: The data in my historyArray is not passing into my TableViewController. Not sure if i got the segue wrong or what i am missing, I checked to make sure there is data in my historyArray after i perform a calculations and there is.

Answer (score 0):

In the view controller that you segue into, you can access the `historyArray` of your `ViewController` instance by using `(self.presentingViewController as? ViewController).historyArray`.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a segue to work you have to control drag from your ViewControllerA to your ViewControllerB in the storyboard. select the segue which you have created and give it an identifier of "History"

Now you can trigger the segue manually inside your function

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "History", sender: self)
```

In prepare for segue you have to check for identifier in your case it's "History"

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "History" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? TableTableViewController {
            destinationVC.dataString = historyArray.description
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this check works if your your viewControllerB is not wrapped or embedded in Navigationcontroller. if it is then you have to first check navigation controller then the viewController.